# O Google muda o idioma do meu site no processo de indexação?

Tags: google, seo

O Google modifica o *culture info* do site no processo de indexação? Percebi que na minha página que tem duas linguagens, o Google indexa somente a página versão PT-BR que é nativa do site.

Algumas informações:

Meu site roda num servidor IIS, é desenvolvido em ASP.NET MVC5, a internacionalização ocorre através de *resources* que é um recurso da plataforma.

**A mudança de linguagem ocorre através de um botão que requisita a troca de linguagem da página através de cookie e meu servidor utiliza o cookie para alterar o CultureInfo**:

`<a href="/Home/ChangeCulture?lang=pt-br">Português</a>`

`<a href="/Home/ChangeCulture?lang=en-us">Inglês</a>`

Troca do CultureInfo através do Cookie.

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(languageCookie.Value)`

Comment: Está um pouco vago para entendermos, existem duas versões da página? Algo como `site.com/pt-br/pagina` e `site.com/en-us/pagina` ? Porque até então o Google não "muda nada", ele indexa o que identificar, provavelmente no idioma preferencial, depende muito mesmo de como você configurou o culture info, se é baseado no idioma do sistema operacional (ou navegador) do usuário ou pela URL.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pronto, explicado ;)

Comment: Há comentado sobre isso na página sobre [Sites multilíngues e multirregionais](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=pt-br) da Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *Google* busca por região, no caso a sua região provável deve retornar como sendo Brasil então os resultados serão em Português, então quando navega nos resultados é provável que só irá só retornar os links com `?lang=pt-br`

No entanto é possível buscar no *Google* em inglês, será necessário você pode modificar as configurações assim:

> [image: configurações de busca do google]

Então no final procure por Estados unidos:

> [image: região no google]

E clique em salvar, em seguida voltando a página do google.com.br vai aparecer isto:

> [image: trocar para o google em inglês]

Clique no link: English, pronto todos resultados virão do Google em inglês, então **se os links estiverem indexados corretamente** irá com retornar com certeza o `?lang=en-us`

Mas é provavel que isto só funcionará se todos links contiverem `?lang=....`, no caso de cookies não sei afirmar, mas creio que irá apenas indexar o preferencial, como já citei nos comentários.

Um link bom sobre o assunto (citado pelo @Randrade) seria este https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=pt&vid=0-736755508896-1511801893234, o próprio link cita:

> ### Verifique se cada versão em outro idioma pode ser descoberta com facilidade
>
> Mantenha o conteúdo para cada idioma em URLs separados. Não use cookies para mostrar versões traduzidas da página. Avalie a possibilidade de usar links cruzados para cada versão em outro idioma de uma página. Desse modo, um usuário francês que acessa a versão em alemão da sua página pode ver a versão no idioma certo com um único clique.

Ou seja links são melhores que usar apenas cookies para checar, então isto é o que vai funcionar:

- `http://site.com/pt-br`
- `http://site.com/pt-br/foo`
- `http://site.com/pt-br/bar`
- `http://site.com/pt-br/foo/bar/baz`
- `http://site.com/en-us`
- `http://site.com/en-us/foo`
- `http://site.com/en-us/bar`
- `http://site.com/en-us/foo/bar/baz`

Ou isto:

- `http://pt.site.com`
- `http://pt.site.com/foo`
- `http://pt.site.com/bar`
- `http://pt.site.com/foo/bar/baz`
- `http://en.site.com`
- `http://en.site.com/foo`
- `http://en.site.com/bar`
- `http://en.site.com/foo/bar/baz`

Comment: Resposta 10/10 junto ao comentário do Anderson, percebi que ele não está indexando em inglês, pois se eu busco com região US, e idioma ING  o resultado é o mesmo(PT-BR).

Comment: Obrigado! Então você realmente não esta usando urls diferentes, infelizmente vai precisar mudar as coisas um pouco, terá que adaptar com url-rewrite (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) e colocar o *culture info* baseado nisto.